# ffmpeg timeout with rtsp

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I have script that capture image from wifi camera with ffmpeg.
It works fine until camera is not reachable due to network troubles.
The script stuck in ffmpeg capture and never exit. Is it possible to have some kind of timeout? -stimeout (in miliseconds) seems not working.

There is part of script that capture images. (there are some manipulation after that)

```
#!/bin/bash
week="$(date '+%Y_%U')"
ts="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')"
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -y -i "rtsp://192.168.64.101" -frames:v 1 $week/$ts.jpg -stimeout 3000 -y
```

I did test on other camera and results are:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "rtsp://192.168.64.112:8554/profile0" -frames:v 1 Ilatest.jpg
```

Does work OK, but with timeout of 5 seconds as

```
ffmpeg -timeout 5000000 -y -i "rtsp://192.168.64.112:8554/profile0" -frames:v 1 Ilatest.jpg
```

doesn't and I got error report as:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
...
...
[rtsp @ 0x55d250488740] Unable to open RTSP for listening
rtsp://192.168.64.112:8554/profile0: Cannot assign requested address
```

Answer (score 1):

[RTSP Protocol Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtsp) indicates there is `timeout` option. I'd try:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -stimeout 3000 -y -i "rtsp://192.168.64.101" ...
```

Comment: just added two more examples on main question. With timeout doesn't work

Comment: Does your source device (192.18.64.101) support TCP? I wonder if `timeout` option forces `-rtsp_transport tcp` and your device isn't supporting it. Do you get the same error if you try `ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://192.168.64.112:8554"`? If so, try the other protocols and see which one works with your camera.

Comment: with that command works. I don't know how to check if device support TCP or just UDP. But if I state -rtsp_transport tcp it works.

Comment: but as soon as you add `-timeout 5000000` to `-rtsp_transport tcp` you get the "unable to open" error? That's bizarre.

Comment: bizarre and true. I did check that once again just now.

Comment: I browsed at the source code a little bit to see if there's an easy clue but failed to see one. Maybe you should drop by at their IRC channel and ask them about how to use the timeout feature (or whether it is what you should use). Go to [libera chat](https://web.libera.chat/) and join #ffmpeg

Comment: ...sadly no response within one hour...

Comment: How about `-stimeout` instead of `-timeout`? See [this](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2294) and [this](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2014-June/022087.html)

Comment: -stimeout at least doesn't throw error instantly. Seems working but don't know if that solve all hang ups. And seems that it is in microseconds!

Answer (score 0):

Thinking outside the box... you can have a watchdog script that looks for the newest jpg file in the specified directory. If it's older than it should be, then kill the ffmpeg process and restart it.

This is my solution for continuous recording of an RTSP stream from my DVR. Network issues that cause ffmpeg to hang will be realized before much time elapses and corrected as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that `-rw_timeout 5000000` works perfectly with me. If the streaming stops for 5s, the `ffmpeg` command will detect it and save the video file before it exits.